# Insert into database, condition based on an insert value in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

I am trying to insert a new row into a database based on another value that is passed in as parameters for the same row.

For example I have three columns -  Name, Age, personType

I want to insert a new row into the database. Should insert 'Male' or 'Female' based on the age of a person that is passed in. Also need to insert 'unknown' if age is not passed in

```
Insert into Tablename(name, age, personType) 
values(@name,@age,if(age>18)? 'Adult': 'Minor'))
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is different to your question but you can use case when for this:

```
Insert into Tablename(name, age, personType) 
values(@name, @age, CASE WHEN @age > 18 THEN 'Adult' ELSE 'Minor' END)
```